# How to install .xapk file from local storage programmatically in Flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I want to implement this functionality;

> A Button when pressed will install .xapk file from local storage with the following path.

String _apkFilePath = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/filename.xapk';

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of: [I am making an .XAPK installer application in flutter. with open_file package I can open normal .apk installation dialogue but how can I install .XAPK](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75118149/edit)

If you're still trying to install an .xapk file, I'm sharing a piece of code that helped me. I'm using the packages:

[archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) (for all the extraction as zip logic)

[device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps) (to open the Settings app in case you don't have the required permissions)

[open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex) (to open the apk file with the Android intent)

[package_archive_info](https://pub.dev/packages/package_archive_info) (to get the information from the .apk package)

[path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) (to get Directories and paths)

[permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) (to ask for permissions to install)

and [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) since I initiate the method with a picked file using that package.

```
abstract class XapkInstaller {
static install({required PlatformFile file}) async {
late List<FileSystemEntity> allFiles, apkFiles;
late PackageArchiveInfo appInfo;
late String appPackageName;

Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;

String appName = file.path.toString().split("/").last.replaceAll(".apklis", "");

String zipFilePath = "${tempDir.path.replaceAll('/$appName.apklis', '')}/$appName.zip";

// this function convert xapk in zip file and moves in appname_zip directory
_moveFile(File(file.path.toString()), zipFilePath);

final bytes = File(zipFilePath).readAsBytesSync();
final archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);

// Extract the contents of the Zip archive to disk app cache.
for (final file in archive) {
  final String filename = file.name;

  if (file.isFile) {
    final data = file.content as List<int>;
    File("${tempDir.path}/$appName/$filename")
      ..createSync(recursive: true)
      ..writeAsBytesSync(data);
  } else {
    Directory(tempPath).create(recursive: true);
  }
}
final Directory myDir = Directory("${tempDir.path}/$appName");

allFiles = myDir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: true);

apkFiles = allFiles.where((element) => element.path.endsWith('.apk')).toList();
for (int x = 0; x < apkFiles.length; x++) {
  final String filePath = apkFiles[x].path;
  try {
    appInfo = await PackageArchiveInfo.fromPath(filePath);
    appPackageName = appInfo.packageName;
  } catch (e) {
    appInfo = PackageArchiveInfo(appName: "", packageName: "", version: "", buildNumber: "");
  }
  if (appInfo.appName.isNotEmpty) {
    try {
      // moving obb file to android/obb folder
      _moveObbToAndroidDir(allFiles, appPackageName);

      // showing popup to install app
      if (await Permission.requestInstallPackages.request().isGranted) {
        await OpenFilex.open(filePath);
      } else {
        DeviceApps.openAppSettings(appInfo.packageName);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      //catch error in installing
    }
  }
}
// clearing cache file after installing xapk
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 180), () {
  tempDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
  tempDir.create();
});
}

static _moveObbToAndroidDir(List<FileSystemEntity> allFiles, String appPackageName) async {
for (int x = 0; x < allFiles.length; x++) {
  final fileExtension = allFiles[x].path.split("/").last.split(".").last;

  if (fileExtension == "obb") {
    String filepath = allFiles[x].path;
    String obbFileName = filepath.split("/").last.split(".").first;

    String obbDirPath = "/Android/obb/$appPackageName";

    // creating the directory inside android/obb folder to place obb files
    if (!Directory(obbDirPath).existsSync()) {
      Directory(obbDirPath).createSync();
    }

    // rename path should also contains filename i.e. whole path with filename and extension
    final String renamePath = "$obbDirPath/$obbFileName.obb";

    try {
      // syncronus copying
      File(filepath).copySync(renamePath);
    } on FileSystemException {
      // in case of exception copying asyncronushly
      await File(filepath).copy(renamePath);
    }
    }
  }
 }

static Future<File> _moveFile(File sourceFile, String newPath) async {
try {
  // prefer using rename as it is probably faster
  return await sourceFile.rename(newPath);
} on FileSystemException catch (e) {
  // if rename fails, copy the source file and then delete it
  final newFile = await sourceFile.copy(newPath);
  await sourceFile.delete();
  return newFile;
  }
 }
}
```

I've tried it and it works, so remember to update the permissions on the AndroidManifest file and you're all set.